# Why does the Electron Quickstart App fail to start correctly on my Ubuntu instance?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, electron

I followed the following steps on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.10:

```sh
# Clone this repository
git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
# Go into the repository
cd electron-quick-start
# Install dependencies
npm install
# Run the app
npm start
```

The output fromm the start command is:

```
up to date, audited 89 packages in 1s

found 0 vulnerabilities

> electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start
> electron .

(node:4081) electron: The default of contextIsolation is deprecated and will be changing from false to true in a future release of Electron.  See https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23506 for more information
```

The resulting window looks like this:

[image]

System Information:

```sh
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy

Linux andy-Parallels-Virtual-Platform 5.8.0-31-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 23 18:44:54 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Node version: `v15.3.0`

Electron-quick-start commit hash:  `2b0dbb098`

Answer (score 0):

After doing a Google Image search I found the cause and the current resolution:

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/26061

This only happens on Parallels at a specific version.